# In bash find number of all descendants of a process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process

Suppose I have a dummy process with six descendants.

```
pstree -pc 101

dummy(101)──dummy(102)──dummy(103)──dummy(104)──dummy(105)──dummy(106)──sleep(107)
```

How do I get the number 6 for the above pid 101 in bash ?

**Update:** To Product above chain I use below bash script(dummy.sh) which is a recursive call to same script.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]]; then
    set -- 7
fi

if [[ "$1" -gt 2 ]]; then
    echo 'descendant process' "$1"
    "$0" "$(($1 - 1))"
else
    sleep 500
fi
```

**Note:** I want to get count of descendants of any process not just above example. The above is produced by bash terminal thus its pstree chain will look like `pstree -pc 100`. If I give input 100 script should return 7(as it has seven descendants)

```
bash(100)──dummy(101)──dummy(102)──dummy(103)──dummy(104)──dummy(105)──dummy(106)──sleep(107)
```

Comment: Is that really how the output looks like? Mine more like this: `dummy(101)--{dummy}(101)--{dummy}(101)`.

Comment: Updated question. I use recursive script to call itself to product above chain.

Comment: What about this: `pstree -pc 101 | grep -o '[0-9]*' | sed -n '6p'`

Comment: This gives me pid of 2nd last process. I want the count like 6 (as 101 process has 6 chain of descendants )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```sh
pstree -pcA 101 | awk 'BEGIN { RS="---"; FS="[()]" } FNR==1 { var=$1; ++n; next } $1==var { ++n } END { print n }'
```

**[EDIT]**

Works for different parent's name.

```sh
pstree -pcA 29076 | awk 'BEGIN { RS="---"; FS="[()]"; ++n } FNR==2 { var=$1; ++n } FNR>2 && $1==var { ++n } END { print n }'
```

Comment: This woks only for my given dummy.sh but not for other processes. Suppose if i give input bash(100) it doesn't show 7 instead it shows 1. As bash(3226) terminal has created 7 descendants of dummy.sh.. It should show 7

bash(100)---dummy(101)---dummy(102)...............dummy(107)

Comment: Please update your question and include necessary info so that me and others can reproduce and test it.

Comment: updated the question, it should work for any process, the one example I gave was for understanding the problem. Apologies for confusion. I do not want to solve only one use case of my example

Answer (score 0):

Try this (1192 is my systemd process, replace with the process number you want to check):

```
pstree -pc 1192 | grep -coP '\(\K[^\)]+'
```

The displayed total includes the parent process.  Do -1 to get only the children.

This assumes `pstree` with a format output similar to this:

```
systemd(1)-+-ModemManager(814)-+-{ModemManager}(828)
           |                   `-{ModemManager}(831)
           |-NetworkManager(685)-+-{NetworkManager}(787)
           |                     `-{NetworkManager}(791)
           |-accounts-daemon(664)-+-{accounts-daemon}(682)
           |                      `-{accounts-daemon}(789)
           |-acpid(666)
```

Sadly `pstree` does not return a version number, so I cannot compare with your version.

Comment: I have accepted answer of other user but just so you know this didn't work for me. It shows 1 even when a my process has 6 descendants.

Comment: I'm running Linux Mint 20.03 but other answer correctly gives me 6 & yours 1

Comment: Works on my Linux Mint 20...  The other answer always returns 1 for me.  What Linux are your running?

Comment: Wow, I am running 20.03 as well... Weird...